# Mostrar un alert al insertar un producto duplicado en la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo una pregunta, quiero agregar un producto a una base de datos y que cuando este producto exista salga una alerta que diga "este producto ya esta en la base de datos", cuestion que lo he logrado bastante bien salvo que cuando me sale dicha alerta, se me redirige a la parte de "botones.php (otro archivo del programa), como hago para que al darle aceptar a la alerta se quede donde esta para poder cambiar el nombre?

codigo "agregar prod" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
<title>Agregar Nuevo Producto</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
  <body>

  <h3 align="center" style="color: #0B3861">Agrega un nuevo producto!</h3>

 <form method="POST" action="botones.php">

<div class="input-group">
<label>Nombre del Producto:</label>
<input type="text" name="nombreProd" required>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
<label>Stock:</label>
<input type="number" name="stockProd" required>
</div>

 <div class="input-group">
<input type="submit" name="agregar" value="Agregar" class="btn">
</div>

 </form>

<div class="input-group" align="center">
    <a href="./adminStock.php">
    <input style="width: 100px" type="button" name="volver" value="Volver" 
  class="btn" >
    </a>
   </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

codigo de "botones":

```
  require('functions.php');
  Botones();
```

codigo de "funciones":

```
  function Botones(){ 

    $action="";

    switch(isset($_POST))
  {
case isset($_POST['new']):
  $action=$_POST['new'];
break;

case isset($_POST['agregar']):
  $action=$_POST['agregar'];
break;

case isset($_POST['pp']):
 $action=$_POST['pp'];
 break;

case isset($_POST['nv']):
 $action=$_POST['nv'];
 break;

case isset($_POST['adminStock']):
 $action=$_POST['adminStock'];
 break;

case isset($_POST['editar']):
 $action=$_POST['editar'];
 break;



  }
   switch ($action) {
       case 'new':

    header("location: ./agregarProd.php");

    break;

case 'Agregar':

    //Vuelvo a conectar con la base de datos, es el mismo codigo que en 
    conexion.php
        session_start();    
        $usuario = "root";
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $basededatos = "stock_manager";
        $conexion = mysqli_connect("$servidor", "$usuario", "", 
     "$basededatos");

        if (!$conexion) {
            echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
            echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
            echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
            exit;
        }




        if (isset($_POST['nombreProd']) && isset($_POST['stockProd'])) {

            $nombreProd= mb_strtolower($_POST['nombreProd']);


            $stockProd=$_POST['stockProd'];

            $_SESSION['msg']="Se agrego el producto correctamente";



        }

        $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! no 
         se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

        $qp="SELECT nombreProd FROM productos WHERE nombreProd 
      ='$nombreProd'; ";
        require("conexion.php");
        $con=conectar();
        $stmt= $con-> prepare($qp);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $cuenta= $stmt->rowCount();
            if ($cuenta==0) {



            $query="INSERT INTO productos (`nombreProd`,`stockProd`) VALUES 
           ('$nombreProd','$stockProd');";
            $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $query ) or die ( "Algo ha 
            ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

            header("location: ./adminStock.php");

        }else { 


            ?>

            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> setTimeout 
        ( alert("este texto es el que modificas"),0); </script>




         <?php
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He revisado el código, por lo que veo preguntas si el producto existe luego de enviar el formulario, lo correcto es que preguntes antes de enviarlo pero bueno, en este caso se puede hacer lo siguiente; una vez que te envié la alerta de "Producto Repetido" puedes poner una linea debajo para volver a la pagina anterior donde tenias tus datos para modificarlos:

```
window.history.back();
```

Esta linea de javascript te envía a la pagina anterior. Colócala debajo del `alert` cuando el producto sea repetido.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    setTimeout( alert("este texto es el que modificas"),0); 
    window.history.back();
</script>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar, se sigue redirigiendo a "botones" pero al darle aceptar vuelve a la pagina de edicion lo cual esta genial, existira alguna forma de que no se redireccione? de nuevo, gracias me sirve mucho. saludos

Comment: claro que existen varias opciones (como preguntar si el producto esta repetido con ajax), pero tendrías que cambiar gran parte de tu código.